# What happens when all ten moderator flags get used up?

Tags: support, flagging

What happens when all ten moderator flags get used up? Does a moderator look if I am flagging the right posts and then refill them so that I can continue to flag posts for moderator attention? Or do I have to have enough priveleges or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flags aren't refilled but you can earn more, [as pointed out by this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117).

> - default 10 per day
> - one bonus flag per 2000 reputation (capped at 100k rep)
> - one bonus flag per 20 "flag weight" above the default (capped at 500 flag weight)
> - maximum 100

Flag weight is something you earn by assigning flags to things that we moderators go on to action. If we deem one of your flags as valid, you earn more flag weight. If you flag something we feel is petty (eg should be handled by an edit suggestion), you'll lose flag weight.

You get +10 weight for flagging a question or answer that we go on to action. +5 for a comment. The same numbers in reverse if we say it's a silly flag. If you get to a point where your flag weight is 0, your flags are ignored by the system.

And you can check your weight from your main profile. In your case: https://askubuntu.com/users/flag-weight/18887

If you run out of flags and you think something needs dealing with, just [hop into the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and somebody will either be able to flag it for you or deal with it directly.

Comment: I also recommend this chat room: [Ubuntu Regulators](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/206/ubuntu-regulators) which is designed as an extended flagging system for users to communicate with moderators.